# Setup Metarank (for recommendation) with its one minute setup tutorial fails with validation error

Tags: recommendation-engine, ranking-functions

I was following Metarank [documentation](https://docs.metarank.ai/introduction/intro#metarank-in-one-minute) and tried to get it up and running with its sample data which I couldn't.

since it is the tutorial and I have no clue to how to fix it, I'm eager to know what is the problem.

This is the course of actions I took:

- downloaded data set from [here](https://github.com/metarank/metarank/raw/master/src/test/resources/ranklens/events/events.jsonl.gz) as the docs says
- downloaded data set from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metarank/metarank/master/src/test/resources/ranklens/config.yml) as the docs says
- run this docker command:

```
docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 -v ./metarank:/opt/metarank metarank/metarank:latest standalone --config config.yml --data events.jsonl.gz
```

but I got the following error:

```
2023-08-01 13:14:32 + OPTS='-Xmx1g -verbose:gc'
2023-08-01 13:14:32 + exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx1g -verbose:gc -jar /app/metarank.jar standalone --config config.yml --data events.jsonl.gz
2023-08-01 13:14:32 [0.010s][info][gc] Using G1
2023-08-01 13:14:33 [0.604s][info][gc] GC(0) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 39M->15M(126M) 5.269ms
2023-08-01 13:14:34 [1.311s][info][gc] GC(1) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 37M->16M(126M) 4.372ms
2023-08-01 13:14:34 09:44:34.446 ERROR ai.metarank.main.Main$ - Cannot parse args: Validation failure for 'data' option parameters: events.jsonl.gz
2023-08-01 13:14:34 
2023-08-01 13:14:34 
2023-08-01 13:14:34 java.lang.Exception: Validation failure for 'data' option parameters: events.jsonl.gz
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at ai.metarank.main.CliArgs$.parse(CliArgs.scala:81)
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at ai.metarank.main.Main$.$anonfun$run$3(Main.scala:37)
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at flatMap @ ai.metarank.main.Main$.$anonfun$run$3(Main.scala:36)
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at apply @ ai.metarank.main.Main$.run(Main.scala:35)
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at flatMap @ ai.metarank.main.Main$.run(Main.scala:35)
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at main$ @ ai.metarank.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:30)
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at main$ @ ai.metarank.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:30)
2023-08-01 13:14:34     at main$ @ ai.metarank.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:30)
2023-08-01 13:14:34 [1.696s][info][gc] GC(2) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold) 35M->18M(126M) 4.442ms
2023-08-01 13:14:34 [1.697s][info][gc] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle
2023-08-01 13:14:34 [1.708s][info][gc] GC(3) Pause Remark 18M->18M(70M) 2.476ms
2023-08-01 13:14:34 [1.710s][info][gc] GC(3) Pause Cleanup 19M->19M(70M) 0.086ms
2023-08-01 13:14:34 [1.711s][info][gc] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle 14.309ms
```

Comment: I wanted to add Metarank tag on this post but creating new tags require 1500 reputations. I would appreciate anyone who creates the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is answered in the Metarank GitHub discussions:

https://github.com/metarank/metarank/discussions/1096